I'm using Preline, and on a dynamic page, why do I have to reinitialize it repeatedly?I'm using Next.js; shouldn't it only need to be initialize once?
I'm using preline and in a dynamic page why do i have to reinit it over and over. someone suggested using mutation observers, but this feels wrong I'm using nextjs shouldn't it be an spa and only needs to init once.
I'm using a dropdown component in preline. Is this the typical pattern or am I doing something wrong?

// utils/preline.ts

let prelineInitialized = false;

export const initPreline = () => {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined' || prelineInitialized) return;

  import('preline/preline').then(({ HSDropdown }) => {
    const initDropdowns = () => {
      document.querySelectorAll('.hs-dropdown').forEach(el => {
        if (!el.classList.contains('hs-dropdown-initialized')) {
          new HSDropdown(el);
          el.classList.add('hs-dropdown-initialized');
        }
      });
    };

    // Initial initialization
    initDropdowns();

    // Set up MutationObserver to watch for new dropdowns
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
          mutation.addedNodes.forEach((node) => {
            if (node instanceof HTMLElement) {
              if (node.classList.contains('hs-dropdown') && !node.classList.contains('hs-dropdown-initialized')) {
                new HSDropdown(node);
                node.classList.add('hs-dropdown-initialized');
              } else {
                node.querySelectorAll('.hs-dropdown:not(.hs-dropdown-initialized)').forEach(el => {
                  new HSDropdown(el);
                  el.classList.add('hs-dropdown-initialized');
                });
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });

    observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });

    prelineInitialized = true;
  });
};




This might not be the solution, but it might be helpful. I went through a similar situation. Let me explain what I am doing to fix the issue.
I am using Preline HS overlay and I have exactly the same problem like you have described.
export default function Modal({
    id,
    title,
    close = true,
    width = "sm:max-w-lg",
    content,
    colophon,
}: Props) {
    const session = useAuth((state) => state.session);

    useEffect(() => {
        const id = setTimeout(() => window.HSOverlay.autoInit(), 2000);
        return () => clearTimeout(id);
    }, [session]);

    /**
     * Get class names for modal inner content.
     *
     * @returns {string} - The class names.
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    const entryClass = (): string => {
        return mc(
            `modalInner hs-overlay-open:mt-7 hs-overlay-open:opacity-100 hs-overlay-open:duration-500 mt-8 mb-8 opacity-0 ease-out transition-all sm:w-full m-3 sm:mx-auto h-full flex items-center overflow-hidden relative ${width}`
        );
    };

    return (
        <div
            id={id}
            className="modalWrapper hidden hs-overlay backdrop-blur-sm hs-overlay-backdrop-open:bg-white/[0.5] dark:hs-overlay-backdrop-open:bg-zinc-950/[0.9] size-full fixed top-0 start-0 z-[80] overflow-hidden"
        >
            <div className={entryClass()}>
                <div className="flex flex-col w-full bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-2xl shadow-lg overflow-hidden dark:bg-zinc-950 dark:border-zinc-800">
                    <Header id={id} title={title} close={close} />
                    <Content>{content}</Content>
                    {colophon && <Colophon>{colophon}</Colophon>}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

I noticed I need to invoke the autoinit() static method when the component is dynamically/conditionally rendered. Have a look at the useEffect.
useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => window.HSOverlay.autoInit(), 2000);
    return () => clearTimeout(id);
}, [session]);

Another example for HS Tab.
const Navigation = () => {
    const session = useAuth((state) => state.session);

    useEffect(() => {
        const id = setTimeout(() => window.HSTabs.autoInit(), 2000);
        return () => clearTimeout(id);
    }, [session]);

    /**
     * Get tab nav item css class names.
     *
     * @returns {string} The tab nav item css class names.
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    const navClass = (): string => {
        return "hs-tab-active:border-blue-500 hs-tab-active:text-blue-600 p-0 pe-10 inline-flex items-center gap-x-2 border-e border-transparent text-md whitespace-nowrap text-gray-600 hover:text-blue-600 focus:outline-none focus:text-blue-600 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:text-blue-400 hs-tab-active:dark:border-blue-400 dark:focus:text-blue-400 transition-colors ease-in duration-300";
    };

    /**
     * Define tab nav items.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    const nav = [
        {
            label: "Account",
            class: navClass() + " active",
            id: "#tabContentAccount",
            icon: "account",
        },
        {
            label: "Preferences",
            class: navClass(),
            id: "#tabContentPreferences",
            icon: "settings",
        },
    ];

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col flex-shrink-0 relative border-e border-gray-100 dark:border-zinc-800">
            <nav
                className="flex flex-col gap-6"
                aria-label="Tabs"
                role="tablist"
                data-hs-tabs-vertical="true"
            >
                {nav.map((item, index) => (
                    <button
                        key={index}
                        type="button"
                        className={item.class}
                        data-hs-tab={item.id}
                        aria-controls={item.id.replace("#", "")}
                        role="tab"
                    >
                        {item?.icon === "account" ? (
                            <IconSticker clasX="size-6" />
                        ) : (
                            <IconSettings name="type-2" clasX="size-6" />
                        )}
                        {item.label}
                    </button>
                ))}
            </nav>
        </div>
    );
};

Again, noticed I am using window.HSTabs.autoInit(); method.
Hope this helps.
